# Admob Adunit Id For Banner and interstisial From Admin Panel or Api

Tags: php, android, android-studio, admob

below code is from res.xml in android studio in which we have to place our admob ad unit id to display ad
now i have to provide this ad unit id from my php admin panel dynamically by api.
it shoud be replaced from server side in case of adsense account got banned

here is the code

```
<resources>
<string name="banner_home_footer">ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
<string name="interstitial_full_screen">ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
```

Comment: Is this about programming? Can you [edit] your question and clarify? Simple admob usage questions are probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Remote to do that [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA7IDiBRCLARIsABIPohj6e205O-z3yE2bKvTtiqqKbe5ZKeSXfYs9HxTiNALzQWLpLWMgVDcaAu-yEALw_wcB)